# Missing DispForm.aspx after replacing

Tags: sharepoint-designer, display-form

I want to replace a DispForm.aspx of a list (SharePoint 2010) - so I did the following:

```
        string path = string.Format("Lists/{0}/DispForm.aspx", "MyList");
        SPFile file = web.GetFile(path);
        file.SaveBinary(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\DispForm_ProcessList.aspx"));
```

Unfortunately, now is the DispForm.aspx of the list is no longer associated with it.
(I can find the DispForm.aspx file using the sharepoint designer below "all items\lists\MyList")

Answer (score 0):

As you are able to see the DispForm.aspx in SharePoint Designer, you can set it as the Default form.

In SharePoint 2010 Designer:
To do this, in the **Form** section click on the **DispForm.aspx**
And click on **Set as Default** option in the Ribbon control.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The DispForm.aspx is not available in the Form section :-(

Comment: What all entries are present in the Form section?

Comment: Only EditForm.aspx and NewForm.aspx

Comment: Did you ever get around this? I'm on the verge of starting over entirely.